# Creating fabric canopy in blender

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I'm looking to create a fabric canopy in a room (6m x 6m by 3m high), whereby the fabric is scrunched in the centre of the roof (like the image) however the fabric also drapes down the walls too.

Any help would be amazing! I'm new to blender and this is quite complex so I'm struggling using tutorials :)

[image: Fabric canopy in room]

Answer (score 10):

You could subdivide a plane, assign its opposite edges to a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Create 2 shapekeys, in the second one scale these edges on X:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, create 2 keyframes on the shapekey *Value*, the first one being 0, the second one being 1:

[image]

Give a *Cloth* simulation to your object, with the group as *Pin Group*, enable *Collisions* and *Self Collisions*:

[image]

Play the animation, it should give something like that, apply the *Cloth* modifier if you want:

[image]

Give an *Array* modifier to your object, decrease the factor so that you have no gap between the different iterations:

[image]

Give a *Simple Deform* modifer to your object, *Bend* mode, on Z, increase the *Angle* to a bit more than 360°:

[image]

Result:

[image]